# Using Ionic 2, I am not able to access Observable after importing it

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

Can anybody lend a hand? Been stuck on this Ionic 2 / Observable thing for 2 days.

Basically it’s saying Observable is not defined. You will see where im trying to access it where the debugger is in the fetchData method in the service. http://pastebin.com/FJKACFeq

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to:

```
import { Observable }                   from 'rxjs';
```

Instead of:

```
import { Observable }                   from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: Then I should be able to do:

     var observer = new Observable(); 

where the debugger is right? 

Tried that. To no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Pull it from here.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

If that didn't work then maybe you can post your System.config.

Comment: That did it. The debugger wont show it though for some reason. You have to log it out in order to see it. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone is wondering this in the future, turned out the Object was there all along, but because of the way the build process works it wont show with a debugger. Have to use console.log. Wasted day and a half to figure that out. Thankfully I had a lifeline haha :)